# HTMX trigger custom event after load

Tags: htmx

Imagine a tabbed panel. I do some changes to data in tab1, and I use HTMX to POST and swap content in tab1 as I go. Now, there may be parts of the information in tab1, where when I change it, I must also refresh the contents of tab2.

I imagine setting tab2 up with `hx-trigger="my-custom-event-when-tab-1-updates-the-special-place"`. All good. But now I'd like to inform HTMX to raise this event after the load/swap of a particular part of tab1.

How would I do that?

Or is there a different approach that would be easier to do in these cases?

It is basically a matter of handling side-effects in the UI. Yes, you did a thing, but now other things also needs to happen.

Comment: How to you implemented your tabbed pannel? How do you switch from tab1 to tab2?

Comment: Good question. I imagine rendering each tab on load and using bootstrap’s css/is implementation. I could easily just hit up backend to refresh tab whenever I click to make it active. That’d be easy. But I want more control of when it refreshes, so I can have it as responsive as possible

Comment: "rendering each tab on load" what does this mean? The client receives one http response which contains the html of all tabs?

Comment: Have you look at this text? https://htmx.org/examples/tabs-hateoas/

Comment: Yes. For initial full page load. And then each tab can be loaded in a partial request, but I don’t necessarily want that to happen each time I click a tab header, but on a specific custom event instead

Comment: think about this again ... Does it matter that you use a tabbed display? I think it is the general question "how to update other content with htmx?". This question is answered here: https://htmx.org/examples/update-other-content/

Did this help?

Comment: That would be what I referred to as `Or is there a different approach that would be easier to do in these cases?`, and yes, that is exactly what I needed. Didn't think to use Out-Of-Band this way, but that might be a reasonable fit, and it also talks about use of events if needed. Thanks for the link. It didn't come up in my searches, unfortunately

Comment: https://htmx.org/examples/update-other-content/#events <-- This would be the closest to what I had in mind. Let parts of the UI listen to a custom event. How do I trigger it? By including the `HX-Trigger` response header in the response to whatever I did on tab1

Comment: Yes, a hx-trigger can trigger a custom even. Please open a pull-request and improve the docs, if you think there is something missing.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way would be to trigger the event server side when you return the content for tab 1. You can find more information in the htmx documentation: https://htmx.org/headers/hx-trigger/

You would need to change the trigger on tab2 to listen `my-custom-event-when-tab-1-updates-the-special-place from:body`.

Another approach would be to use the `htmx:afterSwap` event. To do this you would need to listen to the event on tab1, then manually trigger the event on tab2.